# Use MySQL to match input against saved queries

Tags: mysql

**What I'm trying to do:**
Create a database that, instead of generating results from a criteria, matches an input against a database of criteria.

Sometimes we can save our search results and have a site mail us whenever a new item comes up that meets our criteria.

**Example:**

- Bob is interested in blue widgets, red widgets, or widgets with size > 5
- Alice is interested in blue widgets or green widgets
- Tom is interested in green widgets or widgets size between 7 and 10

*Results*

- If we receive a green widget with size 10, everyone will see
  it.
- If we receive a red widget with size 3, only Bob will see it.
- If we receive a purple widget with size 9, Bob and Tom will see it, but
  not Alice.

**What I've Done**

- Created a list of queries and run them each against the records.
  Problem with this is that I could end up with tens of thousands of
  saved queries (search profiles).
- Researched RETE algorithm based solutions such as expert systems.
  However, I'd rather have this be saved in a database.

**Questions:** 
Is this possible to solve with mySQL other than saving SQL statements and running them over and over? Is there some feature of mySQL that I'm missing - that could show what saved queries match a particular input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Invert**.  Hmmm...  Indexing is about inverting.  Let's see if we can apply that concept here.

I see two types of tests in your example -- "set" operations (color) and "range" operations (size).

Suppose we could build the following into some kind of table?

```
blue  --> Bob, Alice
red   --> Bob
green -->      Alice, Tom

size <= 5 -->      Alice
     5-7  --> Bob, Alice
     7-10 --> Bob, Alice, Tom
     >10  --> Bob, Alice
```

**Range**.  I have a hammer; I want your problem to be a nail.  My hammer is a way to index ip-address ranges for very efficient lookup.  It is so efficient that the "size" test becomes a single hit to the table that will find the set of persons that match.  This, in my mind, solves the "range" part of your problem.

**Set**.  This part is simply to map one color to a collection of persons.

**Collection of persions**

Plan A:  the datatype `SET` is limited to 64 persons.  Not acceptable for "tens of thousands".

Plan B:  a `BLOB` of bits, each bit representing one person.  This has the distinct advantage of `AND` and `OR` now become bitwise operations.  Drawback:  bitwise operations only work with `SET` and `BIGINT`.  That is, until MySQL 8.0, when it works on `BLOB`.  Also, I have implemented bitwise operations on `BLOB.  Another issue:  the bit strings may be very sparse?  So, Plan B is a "maybe".

Plan C:  an ordinary table:  (blue,Bob),(blue,Alice),(red,Bob), ...  Plan C may be the best.  Necessarily, the `PRIMARY KEY` should be `(color, person)` to take advantage of 'clustering'.

**References**

[*Efficient IP address lookup*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) - for your ranges

[*Unique Users*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uniques) - someday I may publish bitwise manipulations on `BLOB` here.

**Bottom line**.  I have given you some food for thought.  And there is a size limit on Answers in this venue.  And this is a bigger task than I am willing to do for free.